# rails order array of active record objects by modified attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model Country and it has a string attribute 'name_en' which value can be for example "England" or "[India]". How can I order properly by this attribute?

Comment: give an example of what you have tried and why it does not work...that would be helpful in knowing what the problem is.

Comment: define what "properly" means to you. Do you want to ignore the square brackets around 'India' and have it come after 'England' alphabetically?

Answer (score 1):

You really need to read the documentation before you can go any far with rails. What you need (and a lot more) is explained here:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

And to order by name you should:

```
Country.order('name_en').all
```